# Theme options on CPT

Tags: theme-options

My theme comes with a section (called Page Header Options) that allows you to customize pages & posts, as below.

[image]

I've installed a plugin to create some events & I'd like to have the Page Header Options available when creating/editing these events. currently i just get the standard editor when managing my events.

So where do I enable this option? I thought it may be in the events plugin registration of the CPT, like below, but I dont think that's correct?

```
'supports' => apply_filters('em_cp_event_supports', array('custom-fields','title','editor','excerpt','comments','thumbnail','author')),
```

Comment: Your theme is paid, so, please, address this question to the theme authors.

Answer (score 0):

The theme developers answered this for me earlier, the answer is easy enough...

http://www.thecodepoetry.com/add-the7-meta-boxes-to-custom-post-types/